# How to log user into my service with Facebook login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I want users to log into my application (which has its own server side) using Facebook login.

I thought about loging the user in, and then send the access token to my server (using SSL of course)

and then my server will check the user id of that access token in front of Facebook (and this way I know it's a valid access token).

Is this the right way to do such thing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the instructions from facebook itself.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/